# FizzBuzz python code with stdin and stdout

Tags: python-3.x

I had online interview test with FizzBuzz program. Write a program that prints the number in the given range. But for a multiple of three print "Fizz" instead of the number and for a multiple of five print "Buzz". For numbers which are multiples of three and five print "FizzBuzz. Print a new line after each string or number.
Input Format: The first line will be the number of test cases,T . Next line will have T integers denoted by N.
Output format: For each test case print the number from 1 to N.But follow the rules given in the problem.
Constrains: 1<=T<=10
Below is my input is:
3
5 7 9 45 95
Below is the code that I have written: Still the output is wrong. please help me to understand the issue here.

```
N= int(input())
for fizzbuzz in range(N+1):
    if fizzbuzz % 3 == 0 and fizzbuzz % 5 == 0:
        print("fizzbuzz")
        continue
    elif fizzbuzz % 3 == 0:
        print("fizz")
        continue
    elif fizzbuzz % 5 == 0:
        print("buzz")
        continue
    print(fizzbuzz)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
T = input("Enter some values: ")
value_list = str.split(T)

for value in value_list:
    N = int(value)
    for number in range(0, N+1):
        if number % 15 == 0:
            print("FizzBuzz")
        elif number % 5 == 0:
            print("Buzz")
        elif number % 3 == 0:
            print("Fizz")
        else:
            print(number)
```

OUTPUT:

```
Enter some values: 2 5 17 80
FizzBuzz
1
2
FizzBuzz
1
2
Fizz
4
Buzz
FizzBuzz
1
2
Fizz
4
Buzz
Fizz
7
8
Fizz
Buzz
11
Fizz
13
14
FizzBuzz
16
17
FizzBuzz
1
2
Fizz
4
Buzz
Fizz
7
8
Fizz
Buzz
11
Fizz
13
14
FizzBuzz
16
17
Fizz
19
Buzz
Fizz
22
23
Fizz
Buzz
26
Fizz
28
29
FizzBuzz
31
32
Fizz
34
Buzz
Fizz
37
38
Fizz
Buzz
41
Fizz
43
44
FizzBuzz
46
47
Fizz
49
Buzz
Fizz
52
53
Fizz
Buzz
56
Fizz
58
59
FizzBuzz
61
62
Fizz
64
Buzz
Fizz
67
68
Fizz
Buzz
71
Fizz
73
74
FizzBuzz
76
77
Fizz
79
Buzz
```

Comment: I got the same output but it shows the wrong answer. as my input is in 2 lines first line has :3 and the second line has 6 5 45 93

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand the problem. Could you elaborate/show sample input?

Comment: the input is given by the system itself. we cant hardcode the N value.

Comment: We did not hardcode the N value though? N is an input

Comment: This is for one test case, my input has 2 lines with multiple values as I mentioned earlier.it has to iterate for all the test cases.

Comment: I am getting output for the first line. not taking the second line as inpunt

Comment: I am getting error "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '3 15' " in the second input line

Answer (score 0):

## BEST WAY

```
c3 = 0
c5 = 0

for i in range(1,101):
    c3 += 1
    c5 += 1
    d = ""
    if (c3 == 3):
        d += "fizz"
        c3 = 0
    if (c5 == 5):
        d+= "buzz"
        c5 = 0
    if (d == ""):
        print(i)
        
    else:
        print(d)
```